# Adding Time to Date variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

Good day. I have two variables in my database. One for the start date and one for start time. I also have end time and end date. I want to do a comparison of the two dates and time. So lets say the start date/time is

```
03/10/2019 9:00PM to 03/11/2019 2:00AM
```

But the date is a variable and the time is a variable for each of them. How can i do that comparison with carbon inside the blade view.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($element->start_time)->format('h:i a') }} - {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($element->end_time)->format('h:i a') }}
```

This is what i had before the i added the date variable.

Comment: Have you considered storing the datetime data in a datatime column rather than in two separate columns as strings?

Comment: Why don't use you use php date() function for clean and readable code.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this:

```
$start = $element->start_date .' '. $element->start_time;
$end = $element->end_date .' '. $element->end_time;

$start = Carbon::parse($start);
$end = Carbon::parse($end);
```

To compare, use `gt`, `gte`, `lt`, `lte`, `eq`, etc. see docs [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

```
if($start->gte($end))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Attribute in your Model

```
public function getDifferenceAttribute()
{
    $start = Carbon\Carbon::parse($element->start_time);
    $end = Carbon\Carbon::parse($element->end_time);

    return $start->diffInHours($end);
}
```

In your blade {{$element->difference}}

[Carbon API Diference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)